# How to get one non-manifod mesh with adaptive point distribution

Tags: mesh, triangulation, delaunay

all
    I try to obtain one triangle mesh from one point cloud. The mesh is expected to be manifold, the triangles are well shaped or equilateral and the distribution of the points are adaptive in terms of the curvature. 
    There are valuable information provided on this website.

[robust algorithm for surface reconstruction from 3D point cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud)

[Mesh generation from points with x, y and z coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882993/mesh-generation-from-points-with-x-y-and-z-co-ordinate)

I try Poisson reconstruction algorithm, but the triangles are not well shaped. 
[image: There are many small triangles]

So I need to improve the quality of the triangles. I learn that centroidal voronoi tessellation(CVT) can achieve that, but I don't know whether the operation will introduce non-manifold vertices and self-intersection. I hope to get some information about it from you.

The mesh from the following post looks pretty good.

[How to fill polygon with points regularly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743030/how-to-fill-polygon-with-points-regularly)

Delaunay refinement algorithm is used. Can delaunay refinement algorithm apply to triangle mesh directly? Do I first need to delaunay triangulation of the point cloud of the mesh, and then use the information from delaunay triangulation to perform delaunay refinement?

Thanks.
Regards
Jogging

Answer (score 0):

I created the image in the mentioned post: You can insert all points into a Delaunay triangulation and then create a Zone object (area) consisting of these triangles. Then you call refine(pZone,...) to get a quality mesh. Other options are to create the Zone from constraint edges or as the result of a boolean operation. However, this library is made for 2D and 2.5D. The 3D version will not be released before 2014.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at your software. I have a question about Delaunay triangulation in 3D. 3D Delaunay triangulation will generate a 3D volume mesh. What I expect is a 2D surface mesh embedded in 3D. How is the 2D surface mesh generated? How about the computational complexity? I learn that Delaunay refinement will give a quality mesh. If the point cloud is noisy, can Delaunay triangulation and refinement handle the noise?

Comment: I'm not sure but CGAL's Mesh Generator or Tetgen might be an option for you.

Comment: Yes. I read the document about the mesh generation from CGAL. The link is http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Chapter_main.html  From the description, CGAL uses one method which combines Poisson reconstruction algorithm and Delaunay triangulation. I raise my question in the forum of the CGAL, but have god any response so far.  http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Questions-about-surface-reconstruction-from-point-sets-in-CGAL-td4658080.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the [BallPivoting](http://vgc.poly.edu/~csilva/papers/tvcg99.pdf) approach?

Comment: I know a little about BPA. The algorithm is one method from computational geometry field like alpha shape algorithm. I don't know technical details about it. Has the BPA anything with Delaunay triangulation? Will the mesh generated by BPA only use input points? Does the algorithm will remove some vertices or add additional vertices?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Delaunay triangulation. Yes it uses only input points and it may happen that some of them are skipped if the distance between points is not homogeneous.